# Import Simulate From jquerySimulate extends Jquery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have this

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Simulate from 'jquery-simulate';
```

But simulate needs extends to jquery in import, to don't return this error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>           at Object.../node_modules/jquery-simulate/jquery.simulate.js (jquery.simulate.js:331)

because final line of `jquery.simulate.js` is

```
})( jQuery );
```

how make this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved , including in webpack.config.js

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery"
      })
```